# srcset inside multicolumn doesn't work at all, any way to make it choose best image

Tags: html, css, srcset

Hi i've got a multi column layout using the following CSS code

```
.grid {
  column-width:260px;
  column-fill:balance;
}
```

Then I've got an image tag using srcset to specify 3 image variations

```
<img srcset="thumb.jpg  320w, med.jpg 480w, large.jpg 640w" 
  sizes="(max-width:320px) 320px, (max-width:480px) 480px, 640px"
  src="thumb.jpg">
```

This works fine if its in a tiny viewer like a mobile view but doesn't work in a fullscreen layout when the columns are being used. It seems the srcset doesn't recognize the column-width restriction.

I never thought I'd say this but it works fine in IE11 which shows the thumbnail version of the image while Firefox and Chrome show the large versions being blissfully unaware of the column-width restriction!

Is there any way to force it to resize by adding a wrapper or something around the images or some other hack. Also any info on if this will be supported in the future.. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the `<picture>` tag works best for things like this.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 320px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" />
</picture>
```